# Getting values from two tabels which are connected via a third table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, where-clause

There are three tables in my DB named questions, question_video, and question_video_progress.
question_video and question_video_progress has a foreign key ques_id which is the primary key of questions.
What I want is a query with which I can get video_id from the question_video table and video_progress_time from question_video_table corresponding to some ques_id and email respectively.
There can be a case where a ques_id corresponds to no video_id in question_video.
And a case where a ques_id does not correspond to a video_progress_time.

```
SELECT 
QUESTION_VIDEO.VIDEO_ID,
QUESTION_VIDEO_PROGRESS.VIDEO_PROGRESS_TIME
FROM QUESTION_VIDEO 
RIGHT JOIN QUESTIONS ON QUESTION_VIDEO.QUES_ID = QUESTIONS.QUES_ID
LEFT JOIN QUESTION_VIDEO_PROGRESS ON QUESTION_VIDEO_PROGRESS.QUES_ID = QUESTIONS.QUES_ID
WHERE
(QUESTION_VIDEO_PROGRESS.EMAIL = 'someEmail@gmail.com' AND QUESTION_VIDEO.QUES_ID = 2)
OR
QUESTION_VIDEO.QUES_ID = 2;
```

The above query returns two rows corresponding to ques_id. What I want is if there is an email corresponding to a ques_id in QUESTION_VIDEO_PROGRESS table then return that email-specific value else just return video_id corresponding to the ques_id if that email does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
select qv.video_id, qvp.video_progress_time
from question_video qv
left join question_video_progress qvp 
    on  qvp.ques_id = q.ques_id 
    and qvp.email = 'someEmail@gmail.com'
where qv.ques_id = 2
```

The important point is to put the condition on the `left join`ed table in the `on` clause of the `join`, so rows without a match are not filtered out.

Also, note that you don't need to bring table `questions` to produce the result that you want.